# How can I link to a file in an email?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

When I'm sending mail form in my app I can attach some files. But in the email it looks like `aeb6fe78271a1f2f51c7b84981b9e8df.png` How can I show link to file?

Comment: it would be a help to us if we see some context.  Give us the controller code, and the mailer model if possible.

Comment: Where's the file located? What type of link (image? download? other?) is it?

Comment: Type of link may be any. It located in the database

Answer (score 0):

if the file is hosted in the web. then checked it out the file link inside the email, maybe the generated file url is a relative path which did not contain the host information.

another solution maybe attach the file as an attachment inside the send email.